# How to rotate Pdf.js canvas output in SVG in HTML in Chrome?

Tags: html, google-chrome, svg, html5-canvas, pdf.js

I am working on a web application whose HTML user interface involves SVG graphics at some point. A part of that SVG is subject to various transformations, such as rotation.

Within that transformed SVG graphic, I am now required to display (the first page of) a PDF file. For this purpose, I am using a [`<foreignObject>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/foreignObject) that contains an HTML body with a [`<canvas>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/canvas) that can serve as the target of the [PDF.js library](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/)<sup>1</sup>.

Here is a minimal example that contains a [`<g>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/g) with a rotate transform on it. The `<g>` element contains a regular SVG rectangle for comparison and the above construct with the PDF.js output:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/2.2.2/pdf.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/2.2.2/pdf.worker.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<svg width="800" height="600">
<rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="rgb(186, 224, 255)"/>
<g transform="rotate(-30) translate(10, 20) scale(1.5)">
    <rect x="100px" y="50px" width="100px" height="80px" stroke="red" fill="none"/>
    <foreignObject x="150px" y="300px" width="200" height="150">
        <xhtml:body margin="0px" padding="0px" width="200px" height="150px" border="1px solid black">
            <canvas width="200" height="150" id="cnv"/>
        </xhtml:body>
    </foreignObject>
</g>
</svg>
<script type="text/javascript">
pdfjsLib.getDocument('https://en.wikipedia.org/api/rest_v1/page/pdf/Canvas_element').promise.then(function (pdf) {
    return pdf.getPage(1);
}).then(function (page) {
    var viewport = page.getViewport({
        scale: 1
    });
    var pdfCanvas = document.getElementById('cnv');
    pdfCanvas.width = viewport.width;
    pdfCanvas.height = viewport.height;
    var renderCtx = {
        canvasContext: pdfCanvas.getContext('2d'),
        viewport: viewport
    };
    page.render(renderCtx);
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

In Firefox 66, this appears as expected:

[image: Firefox output]

In Chrome 74, however, the canvas shows a seemingly arbitrary rectangle from the first page of the PDF (rather than its top left corner) and this output is not rotated, either:

[image: Chrome output]

**Is there any way to work around this issue and rotated PDFs to display within my SVG in Chrome?**

---

<sup>1</sup>: Somehow, whatever resource I looked at, the question of how to render PDF in JavaScript invariably seemed to lead to this library. Furthermore, from what I read on [the library's website](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#backends) the SVG renderer is still very much work in progress and thus cannot be used at a place where customers may upload arbitrary PDF content.

Comment: Regardless of my hope to find possible workarounds for this issue here on StackOverflow by means of this question, I have meanwhile also opened an [issue](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/10810) about this problem on the PDF.js project site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already met similar issue. Probably for performance, in chrome - canvas uses isolated context which is not derived from SVG.
You may use `img` instead & render pdf to hidden canvas.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/2.2.2/pdf.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/2.2.2/pdf.worker.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<canvas width="200" height="150" id="cnv" style="position:absolute;left:-10000px"></canvas>

<svg width="800" height="600">
<rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="rgb(186, 224, 255)"/>
<g transform="rotate(-30) translate(10, 20) scale(1.5)">
    <rect x="100px" y="50px" width="100px" height="80px" stroke="red" fill="none"/>
    <foreignObject x="150px" y="300px" width="200" height="150">
        <xhtml:body margin="0px" padding="0px" width="200px" height="150px" border="1px solid black">
            <img id="img" x="150px" y="300px" width="200" height="150"/>
        </xhtml:body>
    </foreignObject>
</g>
</svg>
<script type="text/javascript">
pdfjsLib.getDocument('https://en.wikipedia.org/api/rest_v1/page/pdf/Canvas_element').promise.then(function (pdf) {
    return pdf.getPage(1);
}).then(function (page) {
    var viewport = page.getViewport({
        scale: 1
    });
    var pdfCanvas = document.getElementById('cnv');
    pdfCanvas.width = viewport.width;
    pdfCanvas.height = viewport.height;
    var renderCtx = {
        canvasContext: pdfCanvas.getContext('2d'),
        viewport: viewport
    };
    page.render(renderCtx);
});

// wait for page rendered, just use some pdf.js callback
setTimeout(function(){
    const cnv = document.getElementById('cnv');
    document.getElementById('img').src = cnv.toDataURL("image/png");
}, 2000);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Interesting, going to try this. This doesn't seem to happen to any `<canvas>`, though; while searching for a solution, I had also done a quick test with some very simple custom-drawn graphics in the canvas rather than the PDF, and that sample worked as expected even in Chrome.

Comment: This works. When doing it like this, the structure within the SVG document even gets quite a bit easier as the `<foreignObject>` stuff isn't needed; I can just directly use an SVG `<image>` in that case.